# PowerShell create VHD

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I would like to create a VHD (virtual disk). I know this can be done with
`diskpart`

```
create vdisk file C:\w7.vhd maximum 10
```

However I am trying to do it with PowerShell. I found the
[New-VHD Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848503),
however it appears to only work with Windows 8 and I am using Windows 7. How can
I use New-VHD with Windows 7, or failing that is another way available?

Comment: Did you install PowerShell 4.0 (which is the version that command is valid for)?  To get it on Windows 7 you'll need to install the [Windows Management Framework 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all).

Comment: @techie007 I already have that installed, no dice.

Comment: I wonder if you would get the new-vhd commandlet if you installed the Hyper-V Remote Administration tools.

Comment: @Zoredache where is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that works for me is to use VirtualBox to create the VHD

[image: create]

And Windows 7 installer to format it

[image: format]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the New-VHD CmdLet is only available for **Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1.**

**Info**:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848503.aspx

Thus, you should use diskpart or the GUI to create a VHD.
Notice **you can use diskpart in a script**. Here are two  posts that should help you :

- http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9910/how-to-automate-windows-diskpart-commands-in-a-script/